# Statement expected, found BAD_CHARACTER Python

Tags: python

en Python intento pegar un emoji y al pegar SyntaxError: invalid character '' (U+1F600)

Comment: Muestra un [repro]. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Pusiste el emoji entre comillas?